Private Beta Extended -- Still Going Strong
The Community Team spent some time looking at Cryptography's Private Beta today, and we saw a lot of good things:  Crypto has a good amount of meta activity (and you are very civil!), you are asking good, on-topic questions, and giving good answers.  The Crypto.SE community seems to have a strong feel for what does and doesn't belong here.
However, being a niche site, Crypto doesn't yet have the volume of content we like to see when we move a site into public beta.  The more great content a site has when it enters public beta, the easier it is to tackle content quality problems that may be introduced by an influx of new users.
This is not a warning or a problem. We re-evaluate private beta sites on an ongoing basis, and have confidence that, given a little more time to increase the quantity of content (while maintaining your current quality), Cryptography will find its way into public beta.

@Ninefingers There's no reason to think Cryptography.SE won't make it to public beta.  Our only concern here is quantity of content, and according to Cryptography's Area51 Page you're getting about 2.3 new questions per day.  My guess would be that if this pace continues you are a couple of weeks from public beta, but don't set a clock by that, it's just a guess.
